# Shorten and compact this small SQL snippet (Count and most recent date)

Tags: sql, count, date

What would be the best way to shorten the following SQL Snippet:

```
SELECT     a.ViewCount, b.DateCreated
FROM         (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ViewCount
              FROM          UserViewHistory uvh1
              WHERE      (UserID = @UserID) AND (ViewedByUserID = @RequestingUserID)) AS a,
             (SELECT     TOP (1) DateCreated
              FROM          UserViewHistory uvh2
              WHERE      (UserID = @UserID) AND (ViewedByUserID = @RequestingUserID)
              ORDER BY DateCreated DESC) b
```

The idea of the query is the pull the lastviewed date and also the number of views in total - it works as it is, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well If I were you I would stop using that implicit join syntax as it is a very poor practice and can result in accidental cross joins. The explicit join syntax has been the standard since 1992 for goodness sakes, it's time to stop using that bad syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style of SQL is a little different from what I'm used to, but this is what I'd recommend.

```
Select max(datecreated) as [ViewedLast], COUNT(*) AS ViewCount
FROM UserViewHistory uvh1
WHERE (UserID = @UserID) AND (ViewedByUserID = @RequestingUserID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, I actually tried that query in MS SQL Query Designer and as typical must have had typed wrong and not noticed as it simply would not have it - hence I tured something quite trivial into something quite strange and over the top!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly how DateCreated behaves here, but does this maybe have the desired result?

```
SELECT Count(*), MAX(DateCreated)
FROM UserViewHistory
WHERE  (UserID = @UserID) AND (ViewedByUserID = @RequestingUserID)
```

**Edit:** Removed GROUP BY clause, since it was not neccesary; thanks for the comments!

Comment: ooh, you beat me by 57 seconds :)

Comment: From (only) a perfectionist standpoint you don't need the GROUP BY clause, since there will only be one row.

Comment: @PowerUser: But your answer is better. =) I did not know that MAX() does not need grouping...